# Boost serialization error

Tags: c++, c++11

I encountered these message when trying to use boost::serialization.  However I don't what did I do wrong.  Would you please help point it out?

Thank you,

Error message:

```
    boost/include/boost/archive/detail/check.hpp:162: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
```

Below is my code:

```
    template<class Archive>
    void nDB::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
    boost::unordered_map<string,macro*,myhash,cmp_str>::const_iterator M_IT;
    boost::unordered_map<string,layer*,myhash,cmp_str>::const_iterator L_IT;
    for (M_IT = _MACROS.begin();M_IT != _MACROS.end();M_IT++) {
     ar & M_IT->first;
     ar & *(M_IT->second);

    } 
    for (L_IT = _LAYERS.begin();L_IT != _LAYERS.end();L_IT++) {
      ar & L_IT->first;
      ar & *(L_IT->second);
    }
    }
```

Comment: The error means that a BOOST_STATIC_ASSERTION likely failed. To find out what's gone wrong look at the given line of code.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, I followed your suggestion and was able to fix the issue.  Thank you so much.

Comment: WHAT DID YOU FIND?! I've been stuck on this issue since this past hour!

Comment: @DhaivatPandya I'm guessing `macro` or `layer` was the incomplete type. Include the full declaration to be able to use it.