# Specialize a Template Function to Generate a Compile-Time Error

Tags: c++, templates, boost, static-assert

How does one specialize a template function to generate an error at compile-time if a user attempts to call said function with a given template parameter?

I was able to get this behavior for a template *class* by using the following idiom...

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass< std::vector<T> >;
```

The basic signature of the function which I am trying to modify is...

```
template <typename T>
T bar(const int arg) const {
  ...
}
```

If I use the same paradigm that I used to disallow certain template *classes*...

```
template<>
std::string foo::bar(const int arg) const;
```

I can generate a linker error, which I suppose is more desirable than a runtime error, but still not really what I'm looking for.

Since I am not able to use C++11, I cannot use `static_assert`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572856/disable-a-function-by-throwing-error-at-compile-time-with-template-class-using-t). Instead, I am trying to use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` like so...

```
template<>
std::string foo::bar(const int arg) const {
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(false);
  return "";
}
```

However, this generates the following compile-time error, even when I am *not* trying to call an instance of the function with the template parameter I am attempting to disallow...

```
error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986611/boost-serialization-error), but it doesn't really offer any insight that I feel applies to me. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hmm maybe you can use this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info)

Comment: An explicit specialization of a function template is like a simple function, so any static assert will always trigger.

Comment: @Sumsar1812, to which link are you referring?

Comment: Is this what you're suggesting...
`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(typeid(std::string) != typeid(T));`
That throws compiler errors...
`error: 'typeid' operator cannot appear in a constant-expression`

Comment: What is `foo`? A namespace, a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`boost::is_same`](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html) to generate a compile-time boolean value that can then be used with `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` to perform the check.

```
template <typename T>
T bar(const int) 
{
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((!boost::is_same<T, std::string>::value), 
                          "T cannot be std::string");
  return T();
}

bar<int>(10);
bar<std::string>(10);  // fails static assertion
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f57c0defef804da)

Comment: This throws an (unwanted) compile-time error...
`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!boost::is_same<T, std::string>::value, "my message");` produces `error: macro "BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1` and `error: 'BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT' was not declared in this scope`. Note that I called `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(true)` without issue.

Comment: @DanForbes Notice the extra set of parentheses in my example? :) Without those the comma in `is_same` is interpreted as an argument separator by the preprocessor. Also, you need `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG` is you want to add a message.

Comment: Derp. Accepting this answer as it is simple and provides the exact behavior I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It seems C++ don't allow specialize template member function.</strike> So if you want to use same interface, you should use other technology. I'd like to use trait_type to implement this.

```
template <class T>
struct is_string : false_type {};
template <>
struct is_string<string> : true_type {};

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
 private:
  T bar(const int arg, false_type) const {
    return T();
  }

  std::string bar(const int arg, true_type) const {
    return "123";
  }
 public:
  T bar(const int arg) const {
    return bar(arg, is_string<T>());
  }
};
```

If you can not use C++11, you must implement false_type and true_type yourself. Or you can use specialize template class.

Comment: Although I appreciate your answer, and it may work, the answer provided by @Praetorian above is much simpler and provides the exact behavior I am looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` were in C++03 weren't they?  Or at least in TR1?

Comment: @MooingDuck Only in TR1.

Comment: C++ allows to (fully) specialize a template member function. But the question isn't about it. Your code compiles successfully even with `std::string` passed as a template parameter.